# IOS Automatic login under wifi Captive Portal

Tags: ios, captivenetwork

Do you think is possibile to login under a network of wifi hotSpots using predefined credentials programmatically stored inside an IOS App. 
This to allow only to people who installed that Application on their devices to use the wifi connection and gain Internet Access overriding the Captive Portal login process of course in accordance with the hot spot network owner :-)

Do you have any suggestion how to get that result ?

Thanks Dario

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this one:

[CaptiveNetworkRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html)

> By calling the CNSetSupportedSSIDs function, an application can register a list of wireless network SSIDs with Captive Network Support, thereby assuming responsibility for authenticating with those networks. Typically when a user joins a captive network, Captive Network Support provides a web sheet that allows the user to authenticate with the network. If an application has registered the SSID of the captive network, however, the web sheet is suppressed, and the user can complete authentication in the appropriate application.